# How can I redirect a domain to IIS local path?

Tags: iis

I have two domains and both points (a record) to my server IP address (xx.xx.xx.xx), my server is setup with IIS (server 2008 r2).
I want to redirect every domain to it's local path, for example:

domain1.net---> intepub/www/frst/index.html

domain2.com---> intepub/www/scnd/index.html

How can I do that?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you want the URL to be when you go to these 2 domains?  Is it domain3.com/frst  and domain3.com/scnd?

Comment: the first one is (what the user type)  www.dddd.com the second is www.cccc.com when they redirected to the server I want the server to recognize the source address and display the appropriate index.html,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like "redirect" isn't the right word to use in your question.  With one IIS server, you can create 2 web sites:

- The 1st site will have a host header of "domain1.net" with a physical path of "inetpub/www/frst".
- The 2nd site will have a host header of "domain2.com" with a physical path of "inetpub/www/scnd".

You can get details about adding host headers from MSDN here: 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)